# Allow public access for images only in AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm new to AWS and it make me confuse, it's hard to use. I have a web app, which use images from folder /images/ in bucket. I have other /mp4/ folder which save videos.

Now I want public access to images folder only. How do I write the permission policy? I dont want people access my mp4 files by entering url.

Thank you for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This policy will allow public access to objects from the `images/` folder in the `my-bucket` bucket:

```json
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "s3:GetObject",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/images/*", 
        "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/other-folder/* "
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Before adding this policy, **turn off S3 Block Public Access** for the bucket (turn off the two options that mention Bucket Policy).

Comment: Thank you, it works! In case I want to add more folders to block, I should put it in statement block, right?

`{
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "s3:GetObject",
      "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/newFolder/*
    }`

Comment: I have updated my answer to show how to refer to multiple folders.

Comment: thank you alot. I have a question, I have used S3 API to generate url for files with expire time, it's unique and change everytime when user send request. But is it possible to prevent user being download file from browser. User have link, can access the file, when they save as, it will block. Is it possible?

Comment: No, this is not possible. If the URL is accessible, they can do anything with it. Some web apps "hide" the URL inside strange HTML elements, such as putting a transparent image on top, so users can't right-click and save the image. However, the user could look at the HTML code and still access the image and URL. It only stops non-technical users from saving the image.